# How to extract or Read files being called by program in immunity debuger

Tags: reverse-engineering, reverse

So, there's this program which reads this set of private key from the same directory, lets call this file which contains the private key "PK" for brevity.

I am wondering if it is actually possible to see the contents of PK solely in immunity debugger,

Here's a screencap

[image]

Answer (score 0):

create breakpoint right after it reads this file then go to memory map and look at address it loaded that file, then select all bytes in that area and right click and use something like 'dump to file' or 'save to file', I can't recall it, haven't used it for a long time, and then after you save it you will be able to access that buffer as file using any piece of software that you want